# SQL CDC Retention Time (Cleanup Job) not working Properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc, retention

I cannot seem to make the retention Time on my SQL CDC Cleanup Job working. Ive looked everywhere for my answer but wasnt able to find a solution until now.

I did the following thing:
- Activate CDC on DB

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
```

Activate CDC Table

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = N'dbo',     
                             @source_name = N'Person',     
                             @capture_instance = NULL,     
                             @supports_net_changes = 1,    
                             @role_name = NULL,            
                             @index_name = NULL,         
                             @captured_column_list = NULL, 
                             @filegroup_name = NULL;
```

Then ive checked my Jobs with:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_help_jobs;
```

and changed the Cleanup Job Retention to 2:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_change_job @job_type = N'cleanup',      -- nvarchar(20)
                           @retention = 2;       -- bigint
```

For all i know this should control the amount of minutes of the intervall, where the CDC Table is cleaned. I couldnt find any other way online how this could be done. Still my Cleanup Job does not empty the CDC Table where i activated cdc.

One thing which is mentionable is, that ive activated / deactivated CDC on this Database before, maybe this has something to do with the Cleanup Job not working properly?

Any help is appreciated.

BR

Comment: Is there anything in the log for the job?

Comment: @BenThul Nope, on the SQL Job "cdc.DB_cleanup" there is no History, only the entries where i manually started it to see if it cleans up the CDC Table.